# TextView created programmatically not shown

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a TextView programmatically which will be shown in another layout that doesn't belong to the same activity but the TextView isn't shown. Following is the code:

Activity:

public class LogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
LinearLayout textLayout;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_one);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater();

View textEntryLayout=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, null);

    textLayout=(LinearLayout) textEntryLayout.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    textView=new TextView(this);

    textView.setText("TextView");
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textLayout.addView(textView);

}
```

Layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:background="@color/editTextBG">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/editTextFont"
                    android:textSize="35sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/log"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/editTextFont"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/editTextFont"
                    android:textSize="35sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/editTextFont"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your container `layout`, has other children whose heights are set to `match_parent`. You won't be able to see `TextView` you add in Java code since the other children added in XML fill all the screen.

Comment: which child element is specifically hiding the view?

Comment: Each of `LinearLayout`s inside `layout`, since their heights are set to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add textEntryLayout to your layout. You are modifying that inflated view without adding it to (e.g.) a layout in your layout_one.

Try:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id_in_layout1);
layout.addView(textEntryLayout);
```